# Login to website (username & password erased when clicking sign in)

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I am using the following code to enter username and password to the website and sign in. It works well and enter the username and password details, however, when the code run clicking the sign in button both username and password are erased and page is reset to ask for account details again. Any help to get around this issue?

```
Sub Wblogin()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim username As HTMLInputElement
Dim Passw As HTMLInputElement
Dim signin As Object

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://sellercenter.daraz.lk/seller/login?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsellercenter.daraz.lk%2Fproduct%2Fpublish%2Findex%3Fspm%3Da2o7e.10547927.old-navigation.3.50f42a97yqWAyz"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   Application.StatusBar = "Loading"
Loop
Set idoc = ie.document

Set username = idoc.getElementById("TPL_username")
username.Value = "cobbler2050@gmail.com"

Set Passw = idoc.getElementById("TPL_password")
Passw.Value = "Cobbler1981"


Set signin = idoc.getElementsByClassName("next-btn next-btn-normal next-btn-medium btn")
signin(0).Click


End Sub
```

Comment: The username and password in the code are correct? If yes, I suggest you to immediately remove it and replace it with dummy values. You do not need to share your confidential information here. I checked the site and find that the username and password field does not have 'Value' attribute. Try to log in manually and keep open the development tools while sign-in to check what changes made in the HTML. I suggest you try to make a test with SendKeys() to check whether it helps to solve this issue. If you see any error in code or on the page after clicking the sign-in button then inform us.

Answer (score 0):

That website is built using the React JS library. As the user interacts with the Input element, React captures the value and stores it elsewhere. When the form is submitted, the actual Input elements aren't used. You need knowledge of React's internal structures to do what you want. I did that research and built a scraper in VBA that worked successfully with a React-based website. It worked for a couple of years, until the website was upgraded to drop support for Internet Explorer.

I now use WebDriver and JsonWireProtocol to automate website scraping from VBA.

Instead of Internet Explorer, in my case the scraper launches Chromedriver with:

```
Shell "chromedriver.exe", vbMinimizedNoFocus
```

This starts up a tiny webserver listening on localhost port 9515.
JSON-formatted commands can then be sent to localhost:9515 via GET and POST, to launch the browser, navigate to a URL, and interact with the webpage using simulated keystrokes.

JsonWireProtocol's use of GET requests is problematic, because GET responses are cachable. In VBA I use a `ServerXMLHTTP60` object to send the requests, because it bypasses the caching.

Comment: Seems like a html form submit,that just creates a webrequest, But the request is computed with js on submit, what is hard to decode (If no clue, except how standard from submit works.) That may be easier reveilled listening to the browser oncluck with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Then you can [build the request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) on your own, without using a button.

Comment: I am a newbie and have no clue what you guys are even talking about :(

Comment: @accadec, As Tom already suggested to you. You can try to understand how React app works. Then try to develop a  solution using VBA or try to use Selenium web driver as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions